# Which protection method to use (mutex , readwritelock ..) on thread inner function

Tags: c++, qt, qthread

I have a thread that is polling data from web service and then sending it to different class to handle the data. The process of that data can takes a long time, sometimes more than the timer interval that invoking the polling function inside the thread.
I would like to protect this polling function,  that is while the processing  of the data is in progress, don't enter the function.

My flow is like this

```
workerThread -> start timer -> that invoking the polling method ->
the polling method gets the data and send it to processing  > mean while this polling function can be called again .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your polling function takes longer to execute than the polling timer than in your function implementation you could attempt to lock the mutex

```
void pollingFunction() {

    bool isLocked = mutex.tryLock(3000); //timeout if you want
    if(isLocked) 
    {
       //process the data
    }
    else 
    {
      return;
    }

    mutex.unlock();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i assume you are using at least 2 threads. one is triggered by timer, the other one is handling the polling data. so the Monitor Object pattern will work for it, you need to define a queue for the polling data and define 2 condition variables (not full, not empty). if it is not full, then the polling could start and then put the data to the queue. if it is not empty then handling could retieve the data, and handle it.